# Terminal emulator of android

Tags: android-emulator

I know that android terminal is basically a Linux shell...but how to install Linux based softwares like gcc,vim, and also other CLI Linux softwares??

I don't want to install termux or other softwares. I want to make my terminal emulator as those softwares like termux

Comment: Get BusyBox from [official site](http://busybox.net) or [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software-hacking/tool-busybox-flashable-archs-t3348543)

Comment: Then?..I have busybox pro...but can't install Linux softwares of my choice.... apt command is not still working....I even tried to get the functionality using an app named botbrew basil but it's not available for y country... So what to do?

Comment: Android has a Linux-based kernel, but is not necessarily a full-fledged Linux environment...

Comment: Then how termux of other applications use them...they are doing these in android kernel after all....

Comment: @AgnivaDutta The packages available in Termux are compiled for Android.. Check if Termux has the packages you need.. Else, you'll need to cross-compile them for your architecture yourself.

Comment: And even if you cross-compiled them, making `apt` work outside of Termux is basically pointless, as you won't be able to install anything. Termux can achieve this functionality not only because the author compiled the packages himself (as @GokulNC said), but because said packages are never installed on the **/system** partition for reals. They are installed in the **usr/** subdirectory of **/data/data/com.termux/files/** itself, so the rest of Android doesn't even know and care that they're there.

Comment: There is also a `jackpal.androidterm`.